# how to get number only from string field mysql

Tags: mysql

I have field that has value kind of store878 . I would like to have 878 from select statement. How do I get that numbers from select statement

```
 select 
     store,
     address 
 from 
     detail, 
     store_number 
 where 
     store (here i would like to have number) =  store_mumber.id
```

Comment: Your database design is wrong.  You should be using a `stores` table with an ID, not individually-numbered store fields.

Comment: That is just plain ugly.  Any answer would not help the root problem.

Comment: if you must have alphanumeric... and assuming the text/num has a fix length then try to get part of the string to split it out. Anyways, i vote for Robert H. advise.

Comment: if "store" is constant, maybe it's easier to compare strings instead :-) [but performance will suffer]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this to make sure is works:

```
SELECT store, address 
FROM detail d
INNER JOIN store_number s
   ON CAST(SUBSTRING(d.store, LOCATE('%[0-9]%', d.store)) AS int) =  s.id
```

But you should really consider changing the structure of your database.

Comment: Unfortunately, `LOCATE()` only does fixed string matches, not wildcard or regex-like matches.  Your answer did, however, inspire me to come up with a working alternative, though it's still a really bad idea, as you say.  If the number is on the end of the string then check the result of: `SELECT CAST(REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE('haxor1337') AS UNSIGNED)) AS UNSIGNED);` it behaves as expected (returning '1337' in this case).  Still, yikes, the root issue of design should be fixed.